# Client Side Transactions in Azure App Service Offline Sync

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Is it possible to leverage transaction on the client, when using azure app service offline sync?

It seems to me that you can pretty much only insert into the SQLite store a record at a time, but ideally i'd like to be able to commit multiple records in a transaction.

I'm using Xamarin with Android right now,but will be also supporting iOS.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, on Windows, Xamarin, and Android you can only commit one record at a time on the local MobileServicesSQLiteStore. This is because changes need to be made one at a time using methods like SyncTable.UpdateAsync, which is how you mark a change as being tracked to send to the server.

On native iOS, the Mobile Services offline sync feature uses Core Data, which does support a form of transaction (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html). If you use these APIs, you still need to make calls to the Mobile Services SDK methods to track each individual change in the internal tracking tables.

Why do you need transactions on the client side?  There might be a different way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Its not really something I need, but just something that would be nice to have. I essentially have a small graph of objects that I need to commit all at the same time, that represent a few different tables. Ideally they'd be foreign key relationships, and I could commit them all together, in a transaction to ensure I don't end up with an invalid graph in my database.

Comment: Its possible to use the upsert() API on the localstore, and then call the MSClient methods (say with just ID for the item populated)  That way the main data gets in & the tracking of what needs to go to the server is set.  However, the push up to the server would still do 1 record at a time, so probably would break then.

Comment: @MattWhetton as phillipv says, you could insert in bulk, but it won't help your scenario, because the Push operation sends changes one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know. Didn't realise the records were sent one at a time, but I guess it makes sense.